# Cannot assign to 'postCount' because it is a read-only property.ts(2540) spfx

Tags: reactjs, spfx

[image]

```
  public seeAll() {
    this.props.postCount = 100;
  }


 var button = <a onClick={this.seeAll}>See all</a>

      return (
        <div>
          <div className={styles.jsonFeedContainerPosts }>{slidesCompact}</div>
          <p>{ this.props.item == 'careers' ? button : '' }</p>
        </div>
      )
```

I am trying to allow the user to click See all to update the postCount to 100 which would show all the lastest posts in the news feed. However I am getting a prop read only error. Not sure how to tackle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot directly update a prop. you can either assign it to a state variable or provide a callback prop. Check this out https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-update-a-components-prop-in-react-js-oh-yes-it-s-possible-f9d26f1c4c6d/